# What does the phrase "before too long" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the phrase "before too long" mean?

Excerpt from where I read this phrase:

> The response to the SDK has been quite
>   good and I expect to start hearing
>   about some great apps and success
>   stories before too long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is an oblique way of saying *soon*.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Jay said, sentences like this are usually a kind of *emphasis*. “before too long” figuratively means the exact *opposite* of “a long time in the future”. This double negative (which is a form of understatement) is called [litotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes).

It’s the same as saying “not bad” when you actually mean “quite good indeed”.

Interestingly, the same exists in most other languages, and has probably always exists. For example, in Latin there’s the idiom “non ignoro”. “ignoro” means “I don’t know”, and “non” is just the negation. Thus, “non ignoro”, though literally translated as “I don’t not know”, in reality means “I know *exactly*“ (with emphasis).

Answer (score 1):

While others have explained the literal meaning of "before to long" being "soon", I would like to opine on when it is used.
The phrase "before too long" is one of hope that something will grow under it's own momentum. Word to spread, crops to grow, etc. Phrases like, "Well, we've planted the corn, before too long we'll be taking it to market." Or, Boy, you keep eating all that corn, before too long you'll be bigger than me!"
This is opposed to the phrase, "It won't be long now" which is used in pessimistic ways. "Grandpa's been sick a long while. It won't be long now before he eats is last piece of corn."
But they are English phrases, so of course they are also used the reverse of what I just said. We like to keep you guessing.

Answer (score 0):

It means before it takes too long time. In your example it may mean in 1-2 years.

Comment: @timur: Your meaning is totally different from Jay's?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on this answer. "Before it takes too long" is the same as soon. I'm not sure where the 1-2 year estimate comes from, but I don't think it warrants a downvote.

Comment: @Gnanam: I don't get your point. I answered before Jay, so I did not see his answer.

Comment: @Jay: The estimate is from the context which I guessed a fragment from Steve Jobs' announcement of a new version of iPhone or iPad Software Development Kit. My estimate was that it takes on average at least 1-2 years before somebody writes a new application and gets rich from selling it.

Comment: Well, I give you +1. I think your answer is just fine -- maybe someone is misreading it, and/or construing 1-2 years not to mean "soon."

Comment: I gave this numbers to give a specific idea of what time frame we are talking about, and added the phrase "in your example" to convey the idea that the specific estimates depend on the context. I am not a native speaker so I prefer not to get too many upvotes, but I think it does not deserve too many downvotes either. Actually I think unless someone is just trolling or obviously talking past the question nobody deserves downvotes. But it seems a norm at exchange sites that you get downvoted at your first answer.

Comment: IMO, downvotes should be for clearly incorrect answers. Personally I rarely downvote - if someone offers their take on a question, that's worth something, right? Unless it's clearly wrong. That said, what bothers me is the people who downvote and won't add a comment saying why. I think @timur's point that context is meaningful here is a valid one.

Comment: +1 to get you back to zero. Perhaps you were down voted for poor grammar (they didn't know you're not a native speaker).